# How to configure 'pull' command in IntellJ?

Tags: intellij-idea

In IntelliJ, I usually have to click 'VCS'->'git'->'show history', and I can get the interface as shown in my attachment here. There are a number of icons that I can click, i.e. 'refresh', 'commit'. However, it doesn't have the 'pull' icon, which usually is the first first thing I want to do.

How to directly access the 'pull' command in this view? I don't want to go back to click VCS, Git, Pull again.

Answer (score 0):

There is "Get" action which will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I usually bind Pull to Cmd/Alt+shift+L (because Push is already bound to the next key i.e Cmd/<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>).

In IDEA / Preferences type git and see the following screenshot :

[image]